# UIImage get retina size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, retina-display

I want to know how can a retrieve a UIImage size, depending on the type of display that I'm using.

```
UIImage * refimg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"people-there.png"];
NSLog(@"SIZE: %f",refimg.size.height);
```

The output is

```
SIZE: 62.000000
```

... on both iPhone 3gs and iPhone 4g. I have the image "people-there@2x.png" in the same directory as "people-there.png"

How can I get "SIZE: 124.000" on retina display?

Thanks in advance,

Lucas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UIImage has a `scale` property that you can use.

```
UIImage * refimg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"people-there.png"];
NSLog(@"SIZE: %f", refimg.scale * refimg.size.height);
```